# Angular loop array with condition

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have data returning from server and based on that data I am showing notifications to users,

> What I'm trying to do is to send notification to everyone except sender and for that I need to loop my data users but don't know how to.

## Code

> Every part is commented for better understanding

```
// group notif
this.socket.fromEvent('message').subscribe(async (message: any) => {
    console.log('group message: ', message); // screenshot below

    // loop group users and except sender user, send notification to everyone else.
    // (access to group users - tested) `message.msg.message.group.users`

    // need to loop here, but how?

    // condition to avoid send notification to sender user
    // (sender user - tested) `message.msg.message.user.username`
    // if (message.msg.message.user.username ............??? ) {
    const notifs = LocalNotifications.schedule({
        notifications: [
        {
            title: message.msg.message.user.username,
            body: message.msg.message.note,
            id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10),
            schedule: { at: new Date(Date.now() + 1000 * 2) },
            sound: 'beep.wav',
            attachments: null,
            actionTypeId: 'OPEN_CHAT',
            extra: null
        }
        ]
    });
    console.log('scheduled notifications', notifs);
    // }
});
// group notif
```

## Screenshot

[image: one]

**Can anyone help to make this happen please?**

## Update

To make it clear:

**LOGIC**

1. Each user has unique `username`
2. user object **is sender of notification**
3. Group users are members of the group that notification has been sent to (including sender himself)
4. The reason to loop `group users` is to exclude sender (user object) in other to not receive the notification **Therefore** everyone in group will get notification except sender

Hope it clears it a bit.

Comment: no one with ideas? :)

Comment: you don't show what object property identifies each unique user, nor shown how you intend to send notifications to other users, which I assume requires sending a message on what looks like a websocket connection

Comment: @user120242 everything regarding to this question is included i also shared screenshot of results that im receiving from server tht means i hve no issue in notification to need show how i send it all i need is looping my received data which i shared. adding extr unnecessary code will just complex the solution for who really wants to help.

Comment: For example, I can only assume that the username is unique between user property and the user objects in groups, yet I can't even be sure that username exists in both objects.  LocalNotification does not give any indication of who it is being sent to.  (Is it meant to be sent to yourself?  Why are you popping multple notifications to yourself with the same data?)  It would make more sense for you to be sending a message on the websocket to trigger this localnotification for other users, for which you have not shown the relevant code.

Comment: @user120242 to answer your questions: `1` username are unique, `2` username exist in every user returned data regardless if they are in group users or user object. `3` is means not send to yourself (that's why i am trying to loop group users and exclude user from that array) `4` popping multple notifications to yourself, the only reason to loop users and exclude myself is to not popping multiple.

Comment: `if( message.msg.message.group.users.some(({username})=>username===message.msg.message.user.username) ) return`?

Comment: @user120242 updated my question to make it a bit clear

Comment: Don't you have the current logged in username somewhere else?  I don't think checking groups is going to help you?  And this should probably be restricted on the server side not to send notifications for the user to himself?

Comment: @user120242 I do have current user but it is `undefined` in `ngOnInit` here is my full code https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/get-user-data-in-ngoninit/191703

Comment: It looks to me like there is something wrong with AuthService or the callback.  There's no way around it, you have to find a way to retrieve the current user, so you'll have to fix that code

Comment: filtering groups after you have already received the message is already too late.  The server has already sent the event to you.  Either you have to fix it on the server side not to send that message back to the sender, even if he is subscribed, or you will have to compare the current user to the message's sender on the client side so you can ignore it.

Comment: @user120242 exactly `or you will have to compare the current user to the message's sender on the client side so you can ignore it` this is what i was trying to do at first, then since i couldn't get current user in `ngOnInit` so I decided to add group users and compare sender from that list, that's why i opened this question.

Comment: That won't work though right?  groups just includes everyone the message has been sent to (all subscribers).  It doesn't help you determine if you are the sender of that message.  You have to find a way to retrieve the current user.  AuthService related code needs to be fixed.

Comment: I can't really say for sure without seeing it, but it looks like you're using sample code from a blog for JWT authentication?  You have to decode the user from the JWT token and retrieve it.  Your await ... .user() ... .subscribe definitely looks wrong.

Comment: @user120242 no it's my personal code both front and backend, and token is stored already in localstorage of phone where `this.authService.user()).subscribe(user => {..});` *[refer to](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/get-user-data-in-ngoninit/191703)* will request for it.

Comment: did you check if the user => {console.log(user)} is actually returning the user?

Comment: no but let me create new app see if it does

Comment: it should be something like .then(user => this.user=user) not .subscribe

Comment: currently is like this `async ionViewDidEnter() {
    (await this.authService.user()).subscribe(user => {
      this.user = user;
      console.log('current user: ', user);
    });
  }`

Comment: oh, so the user is returned correctly?  Is it that you receive notifications before the user has been populated?

Comment: @user120242 yes user returning just can't be accessible in `ngOnInit`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216572/discussion-between-mafortis-and-user120242).

Comment: So two things.  One is that there's a possibility that a notification is sent before the current user data is filled in.  The other is that this.socket is accessible, so this.user should also be accessible.

Comment: would you move to discussion page? i sent you files there

Answer (score -1):

You can loop over elements of an array using [for-of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) syntax:

```
for(const user of users) {     
  if(user != sender) { ... }
}
```

Comment: `Cannot find name 'user'. Did you mean the instance member 'this.user'?`

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Comment: @mafortis add var or const or let in front of user

Comment: FYI, that's not my code nor answer.  I edited in the fix for the error you commented, which should be due to TypeScript complaining about an undeclared variable.

Comment: @user120242 thank you, I am building my app again to see if it's fixed.